# Handle blank values in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have in a cell:

```
=QUERY(A:B;"select A, sum(B) group by A")
```

Problem is that when there is a blank value in column B formula does not compute, how can I make that when a blank value is encountered in column B, it is taken as 0?

Previously I set those cells as 0, and it worked, but this time they are a lot of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit strange, with a very simple example, it seems that everything works as expected:

[image]

Comment: There remains a bug whereby if the first 100 rows of a nominally numerical column are blank, then the entire column is regarded as text (and aggregating functions won't work).

Answer (score 1):

First, Click Tools > Script Editor:

```
function zeroIfBlank() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentValue = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
      if(currentValue == '')
        range.getCell(i,j).setValue(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Second, Tools > Script Manager > Run zeroIfBlank.